# Adding security to privoxy

Tags: proxy, user-management, privoxy

I have this little proxy that i run with privoxy on my server, basically to take advantage of my server's static IP to connect to my office's VPN.

I'm using it on a, let's say, uncommon port without authentication, an open proxy. As my SysAdmin says, `Security Through Obscurity` isn't something i want to relay on.

I did a search on privoxy docs and wasnt able to find anything related to user authentication, my question is: there's a way to archive this with privoxy? If not, can anyone suggest something easy to config and light privoxy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Privoxy does include ACLs (access control lists) for IP addresses. See http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/config.html

> Access controls are included at the request of ISPs and systems administrators, and are not usually needed by individual users.

Comment: thanks but since my ip is dynamic it's not quite practical,

Comment: You can also use a hostname instead of an IP address.  Register for a dynamic-dns hostname at dyndns.com

Comment: oh really? i didn't knew that, thank you sir

Comment: I'd like to leave a web filtering proxy running at home, and connect to it from my smartphone to get rid of the ads and other heavy items. Apparently, Privoxy doesn't provide login/passwd authentication: Is there an alternative (for Linux)?